# discord.py [rewrite] bot not sending message properly

Tags: python, url-rewriting, notifications, discord, discord.py

Recently, my bot decided not to work after changing something completely unrelated to this chunk of code.
When I ask it to send a message to a message's author (`message.author.send()`), it sends the notification but no messages actually appear. I get the bot's icon with the 1 ping badge, but when I click no new messages can be read. Here's the relevant code:

```
    async def on_message(self, Message):
        print('Scanning message')
        blacklisted_words = [
            # I won't show these here for obvious reasons
        ]
        
        
        offendingwords = []
        cursefound = False
        for cursecheck in blacklisted_words:
            if cursecheck in Message.content.lower():
                cursefound = True
                offendingwords.append(cursecheck)
        if cursefound == True:
            print('Found curse word, user notified\n')
            await Message.delete()
            
            words = []
            for word in offendingwords:
                words.append(word)
            
            await Message.author.send(f'Please watch your language in <#{Message.channel.id}>!\nOffending word(s) - `{str(words)}`')
            cursefound = False
        else:
            print('No curse words found\n')
```

Please excuse my terrible formatting, I'm still pretty new to Python.

It also throws an AttributeError:

```
    await Message.author.send(f'Please watch your language in <#{Message.channel.id}>!\nOffending word(s) - `{str(words)}`')
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Try and simplify this as much as possible please, I get confused way too easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the bot tries to send the same words which are forbidden in the List hence, The message gets deleted.

You can do the following, Add an if statement to ignore the Bot.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(Message):
    async def on_message(self, Message):

        #If the message author is not a BOT, Then run the following statement Else return
        if not Message.author.bot:
            print('Scanning message')
            blacklisted_words = [
                # I won't show these here for obvious reasons
            ]
            
            
            offendingwords = []
            cursefound = False
            for cursecheck in blacklisted_words:
                if cursecheck in Message.content.lower():
                    cursefound = True
                    offendingwords.append(cursecheck)
            if cursefound == True:
                print('Found curse word, user notified\n')
                await Message.delete()
                
                words = []
                for word in offendingwords:
                    words.append(word)
                
                await Message.author.send(f'Please watch your language in <#{Message.channel.id}>!\nOffending word(s) - `{str(words)}`')
                cursefound = False
            else:
                print('No curse words found\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send a dm to the author, the `message.author` doesnt have a send() function. You could create a function to do that something like this:

```
async def send_dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(message)
```

And pass the `member` as the author of the message. Then pass message as the thing you want to send. This should fix the `AttributeError` you're getting.

Comment: Are you crazy man, How come message.author.send doesn't sends a DM?